# Next EKReminder Recurrence Date

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, eventkit

I am trying to get the next date that a reminder Alarm goes off, but `EKAlarm` property is returning no value.

This is how the reminder is created:

```
            EKReminder *reminder = [EKReminder reminderWithEventStore:self.eventStore];

            reminder.title = reminderTitle;

            reminder.calendar = [eventStore defaultCalendarForNewReminders];

            EKRecurrenceRule *recurrenceRule = [[EKRecurrenceRule alloc] initRecurrenceWithFrequency:EKRecurrenceFrequencyDaily interval:frequency end:nil];

            reminder.recurrenceRules = [NSArray arrayWithObject:recurrenceRule];

            NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
            unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit;

            reminder.dueDateComponents = [cal components:unitFlags fromDate:[controller.reminderDatePicker date]];

            EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithAbsoluteDate:controller.reminderDate];

            [reminder addAlarm:alarm];

            NSError *error = nil;

            [eventStore saveReminder:reminder commit:YES error:&error];
```

This is when I try to access the next recurrence date. The reminder is found perfectly, but `alarm.absoluteDate` is null.

```
[eventStore fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate:predicate completion:^(NSArray *reminders) {
            for (EKReminder *reminder in reminders) {

                NSLog(@"%@", reminderTitle);

                if ([reminder.title isEqualToString:reminderTitle]) {

                    reminderExists = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                    NSLog(@"reminder exists");
                    NSLog(@"after reminder exists is assigned to YES, value is %@", ([reminderExists boolValue]) ? @"True" : @"False");
                    if ([reminderExists boolValue]) NSLog(@"reminder exists variable works");

                    NSArray *alarms = reminder.alarms;

                    EKAlarm *alarm = [alarms objectAtIndex:0];

                    NSDateFormatter *nextReminderDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                    nextReminderDateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy at hh:mm a";
                    NSString *nextReminderDateString = [nextReminderDateFormatter stringFromDate:alarm.absoluteDate];

                    nextReminderDate = alarm.absoluteDate;

                   //alarm.absolute date is null

                    NSLog(@"Next reminder is on %@", nextReminderDateString);


                }
            }
```

How do I get the next recurrence date?

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions. The iPhone tag is not relevant to this question.

Comment: @Andrew I checked your code and it works. Check that ```controller.reminderDate``` is not nil.